# Microsoft AppCenter CLI - PUBLIC URL Creation

Tags: command-line-interface, visual-studio-app-center-test

Is it possible to create a public URL using Appcenter **CLI**? I required it for DevOps. I'm able to create the group but not sure how we can generate a public URL for the group.

I couldn't find it from the documentation.